# What is so enlightening in the Ferrers diagrams?

Tags: combinatorics

I've studied the Ferrers' diagram. And It's not clear why it's useful, the only property I noticed until now is that once one partition is drawn with a Ferrers' diagram, it's conjugate could show another partition, at least for what I know now, it doesn't seems to be a big deal. So, what's so enlightening that permited this concept to exist until today?

Comment: Young tableaux are defined in terms of them, and Young tableaux are natural for many different ways (sequences of partitions, indices for basis elements in irreps of $S_n$ or homspaces between different reps, etc.).

Comment: Manipulation of Ferrers diagrams allows very easy combinatorial proofs of a number of results about partitions; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions) for one example; there are others [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386542/ferrers-diagram-partitions), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942593/ferrers-graph-question), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334177/combinatorial-proof-involving-partitions-and-generating-functions), for instance.

Comment: Ferrers diagrams can be used to prove Euler's [pentagonal numbers theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) which in turn provides a way to compute the partition function $p(n)$ recursively.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is because partitions are a heavily obscure part of mathematics. Ferrer's Diagrams make it much easier to visualize diagrams. For example, try the following problem:

How many partitions of $12$ are there that have at least four parts, such that the largest, second-largest, third-largest, and fourth-largest parts are respectively greater than or equal to $4,3,2,1$?

Well, this problem can be trivialized using a Ferrer's Diagram. The full solution is left as an exercise to the reader. But overall a big advantage is that there exists a bijection mapping partitions to diagrams.